# dimens.xml(w840dp) not working

Tags: android, android-layout

This seems like a bug but maybe I'm doing something really silly and just can't see it. I have these value files:

[image]

The integer value files are behaving as expected. Inside the default integers.xml I have:

```
<integer name="card_item_columns">2</integer>
```

and for the integers.xml(w840dp) I have:

```
<integer name="card_item_columns">3</integer>
```

But when it comes to the dimens files, only the sw600dp one seems to do anything. For the dimens.xml(sw600dp) I have this:

```
<dimen name="card_width">264dp</dimen>
```

and for the dimens.xml(w840dp) I have this:

```
<dimen name="card_width">400dp</dimen>
```

If I use a Nexus 7 emulator device in portrait it shows 2 columns. When I rotate it I see 3 columns as expected. This proves that it's at least 840dp wide as that integers.xml(w840dp) file is the only place it can get 3 columns from.

However if it's w840dp why doesn't it use the card width value in the dimens.xml(w840dp)? Is this not possible? Can a "w" qualifier not override an "sw" qualifier? I think it should.

I can adjust the value in the sw600dp file and the change is reflected, showing that it's getting called correctly from the layout file.

What basic concept am I not getting here? I find it hard to believe that there is a bug here. Surely if there was, other people would have noticed it. Spot the silly error to get some points. Or give me a clue that leads to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html and noticed the order of precedence?

Comment: I have read that (ages ago) but had forgotten about it. It seems that I can't have a w qualifier work when there is an sw qualifier there, since the sw has higher ranking in the order of precedence.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll accept and up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the Android site regarding resource qualifier precedence is pretty comprehensive:
[Providing Alternate Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

All other things being equal, smallestWidth has higher precedence than Available width

```
Configuration   | Qualifier value
smallestWidth   | sw<N>dp
Available width | w<N>dp
```